# upgrade a triple boot with 10.6.8 to 10.9 - potential problems?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, partition, dual-boot

I was hoping to find a consensus of people who knew about the complications of upgrading from 10.6.8 to 10.9. I see on the App Store that 240 gave 10.9 1 star while 489 gave it 5 stars - so that is not very reassuring as I have a (overly) complicated laptop.

Firstly it is a (4,1) MacBook Pro (nvidia 8600G MT, 1 dual-core processor, 8 GB RAM, etc.) with 4 partitions (all wiped and partitioned by me when I first got it so it was very "blank" at the start): the first small one I stuck on rEFInd as a boot manager, and then the next three are, in order, Mac HFS+ (w/o journaling for writing by ubuntu), Windows 7, and then Ubuntu 14.04.

I disabled journaling on Mac and changed UIDs on Ubuntu so that I can read/write to and from them both. I also have VirtualBox(es) going back and forth if I need them both running at the same time (using rawdisks).

I also have tons of "big" software like Adobe Creative Suite that I'm worried may not work on 10.9. But mostly I don't want the upgrade to touch any partition other than /dev/disk0s2 (which is where Mac is at).

So if someone knows about these two major concerns of mine ("big" software & partitions), as well as any other forseeable problems, I would greatly appreciate any insight before I venture at possibly breaking my laptop :)

Comment: Why would it theoretical touch any other partition except the one OS X is on?

Comment: Well I'm only afraid of it touching /dev/disk0s1 because I thought newer macs put recovery there... Honestly I have no idea it/why it would.

Comment: Clone your disk and upgrade it on the copy. If it works fine, perform the same upgrade on your original disk. Your set-up is too advanced to just tell "go ahead".